# Container width & height sets to 200 and 100 using Cropper plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cropper, cropperjs

I am using Cropper plugin to crop images.After uploading images height and width of is correct but somehow it sets to 200 and 100 which is the default value for minContainerWidth and minContainerHeight of the plugin.I do not understand what is going wrong.I am using following options

```
viewMode: 3,
dragMode: 'move',
autoCropArea: 1,
restore: false,
modal: false,
guides: false,
highlight: false,
/*cropBoxMovable: false*/
cropBoxResizable: false
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/_Billy_Brown/pen/zvzWym/

Comment: @vbRocks Thanks for replying but I am using jquery version of the plugin and how do I set max crop widht and height in this plugin, because I do not see any option to set that.I was using croppie earlier It had that option.